# How to set margin height of multiple divs with same ID in relation to their position in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a html calendar that pulls in vacation requests so a supervisor can approve them. My php function puts a div in each day that represents the span of time off requested. The start, middle, and end days all get unique divs, but will all have a shared unique div id.

My problem is when there are multiple overlapping vacation requests. I want to line up the divs so that they look like a solid line across the html calendar. This means calculating the various distances from top of containing day div and applying a margin-top to the inner vacation divs if they need it to create the appearance of a solid line.

[Here is how it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxgtE.png)

[But this is what I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzNXi.png)

Here is an example of a day div contents:

```
<div id="2019-02-12" class="day  ">
<div class="cal-number">12</div>
<a id="348" class="pto-cal-link middle" href="/pto-requests/entry/348" style="order: 348; margin-top: 0px;">
    <div class="inner-pto-cal pending has-pto-middle" style="height: 12px;">Bruce Wayne</div>
</a>
<a id="316" class="pto-cal-link start" href="/pto-requests/entry/316" style="order: 316; margin-top: 0px;">
    <div class="inner-pto-cal approved has-pto-start">Violette Emmanuelle TESTING</div>
</a>
<a id="310" class="pto-cal-link start" href="/pto-requests/entry/310" style="order: 310; margin-top: 0px;">
    <div class="inner-pto-cal approved has-pto-start">John Doe</div>
</a>
<a id="300" class="pto-cal-link end" href="/pto-requests/entry/300" style="order: 300; margin-top: 5px;">
    <div class="inner-pto-cal approved has-pto-end" style="height: 12px;">Jane Doe</div>
</a>
```

Here is my script so far, which I have been hacking at trying to trouble shoot, so there are a few weird things in there admittedly. For example, the added class "yep height end" should only be added if the div .pto-cal-link.end is the furthest from the top and if the .pto-cal-link.middle's previous element is "cal-number". However, it is sometimes adding that troubleshooting class when the previous element is another pro-cal-link.

I know there are a lot of moving parts here, and I either figure this out through jquery or I go back to the drawing board of how I structure the calendar.

```
$(document).ready(function($) { 
    $('.has-pto-start').each(function () {
        var divHeight = $(this).height();
        var divStart  = $(this).prev();
        var b = $(this).parent().attr("id");
        var d = $('#' + b + '.pto-cal-link.start');
        var e = $('#' + b + '.pto-cal-link.middle');
        var f = $('#' + b + '.pto-cal-link.end');
        var g = $('#' + b + ' .cal-number');
        var c = $(e).children();
        var h = $(f).children();

        if (c.length) {
            c.css('height', divHeight+'px');
        }
        if (h.length) {
            h.css('height', divHeight+'px');
        }
        if (d.length) {
            var heightStart  = d.position().top -22;
        }
        if (e.length) {
            var heightMiddle = e.position().top -22;
        }
        if (f.length) {
            var heightEnd    = f.position().top -22;
        }
        var heightSet = Math.max( heightStart, heightMiddle, heightEnd); 

        $(this).each(function () {
            //console.log(d); 
            if ( (heightStart >= heightMiddle) && (heightStart >= heightEnd) )  {

                    d.css('margin-top', 0+'px');
                    //console.log('ITS WORKING');
                //$(e).each(function () {
                    ePrev = e.prev().attr("class");
                    console.log(ePrev); 
                    if ( ePrev == 'cal-number') {
                       e.css('margin-top', heightStart+'px');
                       e.addClass('yep');
                       //console.log(ePrev); 
                    } else {
                        e.css('margin-top', 0+'px');
                        e.addClass('nope');
                        //console.log(ePrev); 
                    }
                //});
                //$(f).each(function () {  
                    fPrev = f.prev().attr("class");
                    if ( fPrev == 'cal-number') {
                        f.css('margin-top', heightStart+'px'); 
                        f.addClass('yep');
                        //console.log(fPrev); 
                    } else {
                        //console.log(fPrev);
                        f.css('margin-top', 0+'px');
                        f.addClass('nope');
                    }
               // });
            } 
            else if ( (heightMiddle >= heightStart) && (heightMiddle >= heightEnd) )  {
                //$(d).each(function () {
                    dPrev = d.prev().attr("class");
                    if ( dPrev == 'cal-number') {
                       d.css('margin-top', heightMiddle+'px'); 
                    } else {
                        d.css('margin-top', 0+'px');
                    }
                //});

                    e.css('margin-top', 0+'px');

                //$(f).each(function () {
                    fPrev = f.prev().attr("class");
                    if ( fPrev == 'cal-number') {
                       f.css('margin-top', heightMiddle+'px'); 
                    } else {
                        f.css('margin-top', 0+'px');
                    }
                //});

            }    
            else if ( (heightEnd >= heightStart) && (heightEnd >= heightMiddle) )  {
                //$(d).each(function () {
                    dPrev = d.prev().attr("class");
                    if ( dPrev == 'cal-number') {
                       d.css('margin-top', heightEnd+'px'); 
                    } else {
                        d.css('margin-top', 0+'px');
                    } 
                //});  
                //$(e).each(function () {
                    ePrev = e.prev().attr("class");
                    if ( ePrev == 'cal-number') {
                       e.css('margin-top', heightEnd+'px'); 
                       e.addClass('yep height end');
                    } else {
                        //console.log(ePrev);
                        e.css('margin-top', 0+'px');
                        e.addClass('nope');
                    }
                //});
                    f.css('margin-top', 0+'px');

            }
        });       
    });    
});
```

**EDIT:**
So, this is in response to Christophers proposed solution of using CSS grid:

The problem then would, how would I assert row position dynamically? Here is my PHP function that is constructing these requested vacation days dynamically (I'm working in WordPress):

```
    $form_id         = 9; //Enter the form ID here. The PTO form ID is 9;
    $search_criteria = array();
    $sorting         = array();
    $paging          = array( 'offset' => 0, 'page_size' => 25 );
    $total_count     = 0;
    $entries         = GFAPI::get_entries( $form_id, $search_criteria, $sorting, $paging, $total_count );



    foreach ( $entries as $entry ) {

        $entry_id     = $entry['id'];
        $fname        = $entry['13.3'];
        $lname        = $entry['13.6'];
        $pto_start    = $entry['1'];
        $pto_end      = $entry['3'];
        $e_location   = $entry['16'];
        $pto_approval = $entry['15'];
        $entry_id1    = 1;


        $supervisor_location = um_user('employee_location');




        if ( ($supervisor_location === 'Elk City, OK') && ($e_location === 'Elk City, OK') ) { 

            //$interval = date_diff($pto_start, $pto_end);
            if ( $pto_start == $this->currentDate ) {
                $pto_days .= '<a id="'.$entry_id.'" class="pto-cal-link start" href="/pto-requests/entry/'. $entry_id.'" style="grid-row-start:'.$entry_id.'"><div class="inner-pto-cal '.lcfirst($pto_approval).' has-pto-start">'.$fname.' '.$lname.' '.$interval.'</div></a>';
            }
            elseif ( ($this->currentDate > $pto_start) && ($this->currentDate < $pto_end) ) {
                $pto_days .= '<a id="'.$entry_id.'" class="pto-cal-link middle" href="/pto-requests/entry/'. $entry_id.'" style="grid-row-start:'.$entry_id.'"><div class="inner-pto-cal '.lcfirst($pto_approval).' has-pto-middle">'.$fname.' '.$lname.'</div></a>';
            }
            elseif ( $pto_end == $this->currentDate ) {
                $pto_days .= '<a id="'.$entry_id.'" class="pto-cal-link end" href="/pto-requests/entry/'. $entry_id.'" style="grid-row-start:'.$entry_id.'"><div class="inner-pto-cal '.lcfirst($pto_approval).' has-pto-end">'.$fname.' '.$lname.'</div></a>';
            }
        } 

    }

    return $pto_days;
```

Comment: How can an id be unique if it's being shared? You should most likely be using a `class`, as opposed to an `id`

Comment: @ElroyJetson, The id is unique (it is the gravity forms ID) but is being shared across three classes of divs to create the illusion of a seamless bar. It was the easiest solution I could think of to achieve the look. There is probably a better way to iterate through the foreach loop to place the div in the date div, but this is what I came up, and it gets the job done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question, I would make it without Javascript, instead, I would make it with CSS Grid which is super awesome.

I did not make the whole example, but I hope you get the idea.
Just work with [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) & [Grid-Rows](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-row).

With `grid-row-start: 2;` you tell the grid-container he should start on row 2. So you don't need to handle all this stuff with a bunch of Javascript and `position`.

To fill the white space between two columns you could use the `:before` or `:after` pseudo-element which will fit into the blank white space between the colored columns.

```css
#grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 1fr);
}

.grid-box {
  background: grey;
  height: 150px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr);
}

.center {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.row-2 {
  grid-row-start: 2;
}

.row-3 {
  grid-row-start: 3;
}

.row-4 {
  grid-row-start: 4;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
}

.yellow {
  background: yellow;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.green {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-box">
        <div class="center yellow row-1">Jane</div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-box">
        <div class="center red row-2">Chris</div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-box">
        <div class="red row-2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-box">
        <div class="red row-2"></div>
        <div class="center green row-3">Jon</div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-box">
        <div class="green row-3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-box">
        <div class="green row-3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-box">
        <div class="green row-3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-box">
        <div class="green row-3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-box">
        <div class="green row-3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-box">
        <div class="green row-3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-box">
        <div class="center blue row-2">Harry</div>
        <div class="green row-3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-box">
        <div class="blue row-2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-box">
        ok
    </div>
    <div class="grid-box">
        ok
    </div>
    <div class="grid-box">
        ok
    </div>
    <div class="grid-box">
        ok
    </div>
    <div class="grid-box">
        ok
    </div>
    <div class="grid-box">
        ok
    </div>
    <div class="grid-box">
        ok
    </div>
    <div class="grid-box">
        ok
    </div>
    <div class="grid-box">
        ok
    </div>
    <div class="grid-box">
        ok
    </div>
    <div class="grid-box">
        ok
    </div>
    <div class="grid-box">
        ok
    </div>
    <div class="grid-box">
        ok
    </div>
    <div class="grid-box">
        ok
    </div>
    <div class="grid-box">
        ok
    </div>
    <div class="grid-box">
        ok
    </div>
    <div class="grid-box">
        ok
    </div>
    <div class="grid-box">
        ok
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm, thats a neat idea. The only problem would be trying to assign either a CSS class for row position dynamically or directly assign grid-row-start position dynamically.
I had played around with the idea of using CSS flex and assigning order dynamically using the form_id entry number (its pulling in data from a submitted Gravity Forms) as the order number. That worked great for the order of the DIVS in the day class div (grid-box in your example) but still had the positioning issue.

Comment: You would need of course a bit Javascript to add the classes, right. I don't know how you're getting your data, but if you get a Response from an API for example you could simply use the Index of the array/object and set the row class with this index. So ``row-${index}``.

Comment: Take a look at https://php.net/key So `key($entry)` should return the Index of the element inside the array, which you could then apply to add the row class.

Comment: Sweet, thanks @Christopher 
I tried key($entry) but that returned 'id'. 
So, I just went with using a $counter++; in the loop, and that worked! Thanks for pointing me to the much easier solution of CSS Grid!

Comment: @BenCalhoun Glad, it worked :) By the way: You can write `grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 1fr);` and not like i mentioned before 1fr 10 times. `repeat()` is the cleaner solution :)